# Solving a single-variable equation mixed with exponential and algebraic

Tags: equation-solving

Trying to solve for x

```
Solve[((a - 1) (1 + d x^2))/(a (Exp[b x + c] - 1)) - e == 0, x]
```

in terms of the constants a,b,c,d, and e.

Mathematica says

> "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>".

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what might comprise a viable solution. About the best to hope for might be a function that, given numerical values for the parameters `{a,b,c,d,e}`, returns a numerical solution (or perhaps more than one, say, all solutions in a specified interval). Such could be fashioned from `FindRoot` or perhaps `Solve`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression can be simplified substantially as follows.  Beginning with

```
((a - 1) (1 + d x^2))/(a (Exp[b x + c] - 1)) - e
```

multiply the expression by its denominator and `Simplify`

```
Numerator[Together[%]]
(* -1 + a + a*e - a*e*E^(c + b*x) - d*x^2 + a*d*x^2 *)

Collect[b^2/(d (a - 1)) %, x^2, Simplify]
(* (b^2*(-1 + a*(1 + e - e*E^(c + b*x))))/((-1 + a)*d) + b^2*x^2 *)
```

Next, replace `x` by `y/b`

```
% /. x -> y/b
(* (b^2*(-1 + a*(1 + e - e*E^(c + y))))/((-1 + a)*d) + y^2 *)
```

and introduce new constants that aggregate the old ones

```
{s, r} = Simplify[CoefficientList[%[[1]], Exp[y]]]
(* {(b^2*(-1 + a + a*e))/((-1 + a)*d), (a*b^2*e*E^c)/(d - a*d)} *)
```

With these substitutions, the original equation becomes

```
s + r Exp[y] + y^2 == 0
```

Even though now there are but two independent parameters, `r` and `s`, `Solve` and `Reduce` nonetheless cannot make progress.  However, a numerical solution is obtained easily.

```
ContourPlot3D[s+ Exp[y] r + y^2 == 0, {r, -2, 2}, {s, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  AxesLabel -> {r, s, b x}, ImageSize -> 500, Mesh -> None,
  BaseStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontSize -> 14]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]